# CSS transition not working when React state is being changed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, sass

Whenever the user clicks on any accordion, it should view/hide its content with some transition. Transition is working only when the accordion is in the closed state and going to be opened but not working in the case of the open state!

Please have a look at this screencast to have a more clear overview: [screen recording](https://streamable.com/v15u2m). Do you see? Not closing smoothly like during opening, however it should be.

What's wrong with my code? Here is my full code with CSS.

`jsx`

```
import styles from './ChapterList.module.scss';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {AccordionCloseIcon, AccordionShowIcon} from "../../../components/icons/Accordion";

const dummyChapterContents = [{
    id: 'c1',
    type: 'লেকচার ক্লাস ০১',
    title: 'পৌণঃপুনিক থেকে সাধারণ ভগ্নাংশে রূপান্তর থেকে',
    data: '1 Feb 2023 '
}, {id: 'c2', title: 'Lorem ipsum'}, {id: 'c3', title: 'Lorem ipsum'}]

const ChapterList = ({chapters, onSelectChapterContent}) => {
    const [activeChapterId, setActiveChapterId] = useState(null);
    const [activeChapterContentId, setActiveChapterContentId] = useState(null);
    const [activeChapterContents, setActiveChapterContents] = useState([]);

    const handleChapterClick = (id) => {
        setActiveChapterId(activeChapterId === id ? null : id);
    };

    const handleChapterContentClick = (info) => {
        setActiveChapterContentId(info?.id);
        onSelectChapterContent(info)
    };

    // chapter contents related logic go here
    const renderContent = () => {
        // API logics [loading, fill/empty, error] to be written
        if (!activeChapterContents.length) {
            return null;
        }

        return (
            <ul>
                {activeChapterContents.map((item) => (
                    <li
                        key={`${activeChapterId}-${item?.id}`}
                        className={`${styles.chapter_content__item} ${
                            activeChapterContentId === item?.id && styles.chapter_content__item__active
                        }`}
                        onClick={() => handleChapterContentClick(item)}
                    >
                        {item?.title}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        );
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (activeChapterId) {
            // fetch chapter contents from API
            setActiveChapterContents(dummyChapterContents)
        }
    }, [activeChapterId])

    return (
        <div className={`col-span-full md:col-span-5 ${styles.chapter_list}`}>
            {chapters.map((chapter) => (
                <div
                    key={chapter.id}
                    className={`${styles.chapter_item} ${activeChapterId === chapter.id ? styles.active : ''}`}
                >
                    <div className={styles.chapter_meta_info} onClick={() => handleChapterClick(chapter.id)}>
                        <div>
                            <div className={styles.chapter_title}>{chapter.title}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.chapter_icon}>
                            {
                                activeChapterId === chapter.id ? <AccordionShowIcon/> : <AccordionCloseIcon/>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className={styles.chapter_content}>
                        {activeChapterId === chapter?.id && renderContent()}
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default ChapterList;
```

`scss`

```
.chapter_list {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  row-gap: 12px;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    row-gap: 16px;
  }
}

.chapter_item {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border: 1px solid #D0DEEF;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 16px;

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px 12px;
  }

  .chapter_meta_info {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;

    .chapter_title {
      font-family: 'Baloo Da 2';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 500;
      font-size: 16px;
      line-height: 27px;
      color: #343B6D;

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        font-weight: 600;
      }
    }

    .chapter_icon {
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
  }

  .chapter_content {
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    padding: 0 10px;

    &__item {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      font-size: 1rem;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #333;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
      transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;

      &:hover {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
      }

      &__active {
        background-color: #f6f6f6;
        color: #0070f3;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        padding: 1rem 0;
      }
    }
  }

  &.active {
    .chapter_meta_info {
      .chapter_title {
      }

      .chapter_icon {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }

    .chapter_content {
      max-height: 600px;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an element from the DOM and adding it, meaning changing the structure of the DOM is not simply "animatable". This is why we see libraries like [Framer Motion](https://www.framer.com/motion/) and [Gsap Flip](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/Flip/).

And this is what you are doing with `activeChapterId === chapter?.id && renderContent()`.

The easiest way to have the output you are looking for is to render the content without a condition, hide it and reveal it with CSS:

```js
<div className={styles.chapter_content}>
  {renderContent()}
</div>
```